# SMHasher setup?

Tags: testing, hash

The [SMHasher](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher) test suite for hash functions is touted as the best of the lot. But the latest version I've got (from [rurban](https://github.com/rurban/smhasher)) gives absolutely no clue on how to check your proposed hash function (it does include an impressive battery of hash functions, but some of interest --if only for historic value-- are missing). Add that I'm a complete CMake newbie.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple. You just need to install CMake.

### Building SMHasher

To build SMHasher on a Linux/Unix machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/rurban/smhasher
cd smhasher/
git submodule init
git submodule update
cmake .
make
```

### Adding a new hash function

To add a new function, you can edit just three files: `Hashes.cpp`, `Hashes.h` and `main.cpp`.

For example, I will add the [ElfHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PJW_hash_function):

```
unsigned long ElfHash(const unsigned char *s)
{
    unsigned long   h = 0, high;
    while (*s)
    {
        h = (h << 4) + *s++;
        if (high = h & 0xF0000000)
            h ^= high >> 24;
        h &= ~high;
    }
    return h;
}
```

First, need to modify it slightly to take a seed and length:

```
uint32_t ElfHash(const void *key, int len, uint32_t seed)
{
    unsigned long h = seed, high;
    const uint8_t *data = (const uint8_t *)key;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        h = (h << 4) + *data++;
        if (high = h & 0xF0000000)
            h ^= high >> 24;
        h &= ~high;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Add this function definition to `Hashes.cpp`. Also add the following to `Hashes.h`:

```
uint32_t ElfHash(const void *key, int len, uint32_t seed);
inline void ElfHash_test(const void *key, int len, uint32_t seed, void *out) {
    *(uint32_t *) out = ElfHash(key, len, seed);
}
```

In file `main.cpp` add the following line into array `g_hashes`:

```
{ ElfHash_test, 32, 0x0, "ElfHash", "ElfHash 32-bit", POOR, {0x0} },
```

(The third value is self-verification. You will learn this only after running the test once.)

Finally, rebuild and run the test:

```
make
./SMHasher ElfHash
```

It will show you all the tests that this hash function fails. (It is *very bad*.)